# Э-мейл, э-майл, е-мейл, е-майл, эмайл, имейл, э-почта, e-mail?

Tags: заимствования

Какова наиболее верная русификация слова e-mail? Почему?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно словарю Лопатина - **имейл** [http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=имейл&all=x](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB&all=x)

Answer (score 1):

В английском, из которого взялось это слово, со временем почти перестали записывать его с дефисом - в быту так удобнее (напр. при использовании слова в качестве глагола) и не отвлекает внимание читающего на ненужные попытки расшифровки аббревиатуры - при том, что смысл слова давно всем ясен. В русском в разное время были разные рекомендации (начиная с русской компьютерной терминологии от переводчиков "Майкрософта"), но я (по упомянутой причине и ввиду близости к оригиналу по произношению) считаю наиболее оправданным написание "**имейл**" и надеюсь, что в конце концов циркуляры придут именно к этому.

Answer (score 1):

Не устоялось, но рекомендацию Лопатина лично я считаю странной. Просто чтобы отличалось от английского оригинала как можно больше, что ли?

Comment: Транслитерация английского слова. В русском здесь нет никаких причин для дефиса, а произносится слово по литературной норме ближе всего именно к "имейл"

Comment: Но вряд ли вы, впервые увидев этот *имейл*, сразу сообразите, в чем дело.